# Searching inside an EAR/WAR file for a jar by jar name

Tags: unix, war, ear

I'm trying to find which command I can use in order to search for a known jar file name, in a specific unknown .ear file (of many) in a specific directory.

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To search for a `jar` in a single `ear` file you can try:

```
unzip -l some_file.ear | grep -i known_file.jar
```

If you want to search through more than one `ear` file, you can feed them one by one to the same command:

```
for file in specific/directory/*.ear; do echo "$file: "; unzip -l $file | grep -i known_file.jar; done
```

Which will list all the ear files and any potential matches within them.

Answer (score 1):

The [`EAR`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAR_(file_format)) file-format is an extension of the `JAR` format and thus a simple `ZIP` container.

You can open it with any program or library that is able to handle the zip format. You can e.g. use java's inbuilt [`java.util.zip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) package to load the ear file and then walk its contents until you find what you're looking for.